# Converting HTML Links to URL's to put into text editor

Tags: html, url, hyperlink

I get emailed a list of links to put into an html editor for one of my volunteer jobs, but the problem is, I don't want to do it one by one.

Is there any trick to this? I've googled, youtubed, and still have yet to find a good answer.

i.e.

[Help for renters](http://mail01.tinyletterapp.com/ThisWeekinExperimental/this-week-in-experimental-vol-78/20512661-www.consumerfinance.gov/coronavirus/mortgage-and-housing-assistance/renter-protections/?c=05d4d2ee-c0f0-7ae0-d9b7-85f32a2633db)

[GIG Fund](http://mail01.tinyletterapp.com/ThisWeekinExperimental/this-week-in-experimental-vol-78/20512665-www.artsmidwest.org/programs/gigfund?c=05d4d2ee-c0f0-7ae0-d9b7-85f32a2633db)

[Springboard for the arts](http://mail01.tinyletterapp.com/ThisWeekinExperimental/this-week-in-experimental-vol-78/20512669-springboardforthearts.org/coronavirus/?c=05d4d2ee-c0f0-7ae0-d9b7-85f32a2633db)

[Africa Creative Defence Network](http://Africa%20Creative%20Defence%20Network)

desired output:

*list of url's

*Editing post: I am trying to extract links from a pdf file.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty easy using Python and BeautifulSoup.

Check out [this link](https://pythonprogramminglanguage.com/get-links-from-webpage/) for a really easy script that will take in a URL for a webpage and will spit back out a list of links on that page:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
import re

req = Request("http://slashdot.org")
html_page = urlopen(req)

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_page, "lxml")

links = []
for link in soup.findAll('a'):
    links.append(link.get('href'))

print(links)
```

Comment: thanks for this answer -- when i run this code i get an empty array -- using current versions of python, bs4, pip lxml, and requests -- any thoughts?

Comment: also worth noting that the url ends in a .pdf -- do you think that makes a diff?

Comment: Yep, makes a big difference. The code I gave only works on an HTML source document. Asking about extracting all URLs from a PDF is an entirely different question.

Comment: ahh thanks -- there appears to be this link going through the process: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/extract-hyperlinks-from-pdf-in-python/

Comment: I want to find a solution and then Ill update this question.

Comment: One option is you could use a PDF to HTML conversion tool and use the same method I posted above :) check out this link: https://www.craig-edmonds.com/extract-urls-pdf-file-for-free/